# How to “apologize for the inconvenience” customer and invite to restaurant again - in the most short way?

Tags: phrase-usage

How to say apologize for the inconvenience customer and invite to restaurant again - in the most short way?

It looks that in English I should say that I am apologize (for something). So we apologize and invite again is invalid and should be we apologize for the inconvenience and invite again??? In Polish is not to be specific you just "apologize" not need to say "for what" it is optional

Consider such case - restaurant has some emergency and you want politely ask customer to come again?

How it will say native speaker in short (not what build long sentences but pass message).

What phrase will use he/she?

Answer (score 4):

The exact wording would depend on details. But you can say something like, "We regret that the meeting had to be cancelled because of the weather. We apologize for the inconvenience. We are rescheduling the meeting for March 3 and we hope you will be able to attend."

If there is not a specific time schedule, but rather something didn't work out when people showed up, you might say something like, "We regret that the building was on fire when you visited. We invite you to visit again at your convenience."

Basically, it's common to say "we regret that ..." or "we apologize for the inconvenience" or "we apologize for the error", and then say something about "rescheduling" or "please come again".

Comment: I want to use it in context of restaurant. I know "We apologize for the inconvenience" from [corpora]9http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/). I want to say "sorry" and invite again in polite/official way.

Comment: @Chameleon: When you say "in the context of a restaurant," who is talking to who? Is the manager of the restaurant apologizing to a customer? A customer to a host? A potential worker who was supposed to show up for a job interview? A friend to another friend who was supposed to meet at the restaurant?

Comment: @J.R. I should give more context information. This is talk between restaurateur/manager/waiter and customer. Customer comes to restaurant and manager says in case of emergency i.e. no water.

Answer (score 0):

I was talking with my friend he said - that is common in Google = 11e6 :)

*We are experiencing [some issue i.e. some kind of water issue] - We apologize for any inconvenience and please (visit us|come back again).*

Or

We apologize for any inconvenience and please (visit us|come back again) soon [in the future]._

I think that is the best translation.

Comment: It should be 'we apologize for **your** inconvenience'.

Comment: @NS.X. *I apologize for **the** inconvenience* (or **any** inconvenience) is more idiomatic English than **your** - although all three would be understood by a native speaker: https://www.google.co.uk/?&q=%22i+apologize+for+the+inconvenience%22 and https://www.google.co.uk/?&q=%22i+apologize+for+your+inconvenience%22

Comment: @Matt May you suggest which phrase is the most correct instead _some kind moderation_ which I not like at all in this question. I want to finish this question. It looks that is hard to answer since really idiomatic.

Comment: @Chameleon: As I said,  **any**, **the** and **your** are all correct, but **the** is the most idiomatic (i.e. the "most correct").

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner or the restaurant manager and you wish to apologize to your customers because the restaurant is temporarily closed. You can say the following on a notice

- The management of *Slow Food* regret that the restaurant is temporarily closed  [**due to unforeseen circumstances**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/due-to-unforeseen-circumstances). We apologize profusely for [**any inconvenience**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/inconvenience_1) this may have caused our customers.
- Customers who have made [**party reservations**](https://greensrestaurant.com/reservations/large-party-reservations/) are invited to contact the restaurant at [PHONE NUMBER] to arrange a new booking.
- We look forward to seeing you again when the restaurant is reopened on [DATE]

  OR
- We thank you for your patience and hope you come back to see us.

Answer (score 0):

The manager might well say one of:

> - I apologize for the inconvenience. I hope that you will visit us again when we will be able to serve you better.
> - I am sorry that we were not able to provide you with our usual service. I hope that you will give us another chance on a different day.
> - I am so sorry for the unexpected problem. Please accept my apologies. I would like to invite you to return on another day when we can serve you better.

Note that one should not say "invite to restaurant again" but rather "invite **the customer** to **the** restaurant again". In that construction, one should say who is being invited, and "restaurant" requires an article. Simialerly, one should not say or write 'How it will say native speaker" but rather "How will a native speaker say that ..."