# How to "apologize for the inconvenience" customer and invite to restaurant again - in the most short way?

Tags: phrase-usage

How to say *apologize for the inconvenience* customer and invite to restaurant again - in the most short way?

Consider such case - restaurant has some *emergency* and you want politely ask customer to come again?

How it will say native speaker in short (not what build long sentences but pass message).

What phrase will use he/she?

Comment: Hi Chameleon, please do not repost questions you've already asked. If you have more details to add to the initial question, please edit it to add them (the question will automatically be bumped when you do so). Thanks!

Comment: @WendiKidd Why are you mark question with different context and not as generic like others as duplicate. I am not understand. Many people ask me to specify more context. Should I replace previous question and delete previous valid answers or should open again next question? Can you help me if you are moderator?

Comment: @WendiKidd can you read /Matt/ last comment [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5985/how-to-say-politely-we-apologize-and-invite-again) since you are in contradiction to /Matt/ and me too. Please decide what to do: 1. delete previous and create new. 2. make this new question as not duplicate. 3. create another question like this with comment please not mark as duplicate??? I am confused now.

Comment: Chameleon, I've replied to you on the original question.

Comment: @WendiKidd There is not original question. This is another question. **Please solve contradiction in moderation and suggest solution**. I do not want delete previous question but create another but if **have to** want delete both and create one. Not understand what you replied in please be spefic and solve contradiction: 1. delete previous and create new. 2. make this new question as not duplicate. 3. create another question like this with comment please not mark as duplicate??? I want help from you not comments.

Comment: @WendiKidd BTW **duplicated == exact match** and similar == fuzzy match (i.e. 20% or 80% but not 100%). Because of it I think that is wrong moderation to kill wide question with specific one. I am still waiting on solution /Matt/ replaced  different question with this one but it wrong solution and want delete both since it becomes mess :)